# redirecting with wrong parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app that allows users to follow/unfollow other users. This relationship is stored in the `relationships` table, which has the fields `id`, `follower_id`, and `followed_id`.  When I call the `destroy` method to unfollow a user, it destroys the relationship, but then tries to redirect back to the followed user by using the destroyed relationships `id` and not the users `id`. This `id` is/was stored in the `followed_id` field of the relationships table. I don't know how to trouble shoot this in rails.

Here is the relationship controller

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @relationship = Relationship.new
        @relationship.followed_id = params[:followed_id]
        @relationship.follower_id = current_user.id
        if @relationship.save
            redirect_to User.find params[:followed_id]
        else
            flash[:error] = "Couldn't Follow"
            redirect_to root_url
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @relationship = Relationship.find(params[:id])
        @relationship.destroy
        redirect_to user_path params[:id]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace:

```
redirect_to user_path params[:id]
```

with:

```
redirect_to user_path(@relationship.followed_id)
```

`@relationship` is removed from db but you still have the object in memory.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I was trying 'redirect_to user_path params[@relationship.followed_id]' and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.  When the tutorials you are following are wrong it makes things very hard.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
def destroy
        @relationship = Relationship.find(params[:id])
        @followed_user_id = @relationship.followed_id
        @relationship.destroy
        redirect_to user_path @followed_user_id
    end
```

Hope this may help :)

Comment: its useless to do an additional db call in this case

Comment: in you edit, beware of naming, an id is an id not a user... well you'd end up with my answer...

Comment: @apneadiving: thanks you are right. I just editted not to do a db call.